# Unable to bind a combobox value to a label

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to bind my combobox text/value to a label. I am able to bind a slider to the label but when I use the same method to bind a combobox, it shows no results. Please advice. Thanks.

```
<!--Works-->

    <Slider Name="slider2" Width="144"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider2}"/>

<!--Not working-->

    <ComboBox Name="secondaryTable" Width="120">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="A"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="B"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="C"/>
                </ComboBox>
    <Label Content="{Binding Value, ElementName=secondaryTable}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind to **`SelectedItem.Content`** property.

```
<Label Content="{Binding SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=secondaryTable}"/>
```

**OR**

**`Text`** property of ComboBox.

```
<Label Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=secondaryTable}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to the SelectedValue  property

```
<Label Content="{Binding SelectedValue.Content, ElementName=secondaryTable}"/>
```